# How to add UITextfield on click of UIButton and make it editable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a UIButton and I am trying to develop an editable UITextField onclick of UIButton. 
Basically, I want the user to click on the button and edit the text and save it for future use.

So currently I have:

```
[notes_button addTarget:self action:@selector(editNote) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I am not sure how to get a popup like UITextField onclick and add UITextField in editNote function.

Comment: Do you want that after the user presses the _notes_button_ a uitextfield becomes editable? or it should appear at that point?

Comment: after the user presses the notes_button a uitextfield should appear and it should be editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. First make your textfield hide on viewdidload - then on button push, fade it in.. make it editable, and pop up keyboard for user.

```
//viewDidLoad

yourTextField.alpha = 0;
yourTextField.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

-(void)editNote {

            //fade in text field after button push
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
            yourTextField.alpha = 1;

            [UIView commitAnimations];

           //make text field editable
           yourTextField.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

          //pop up keyboard
           [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

**------- Update --------**

Now that you have described what you are trying to do a little better. You will want to create an entirely new ViewController with the fields (UITextFields etc) on this new view controller.

On button click you will code:

```
TextFieldViewController * vc = [(TextFieldViewController *)[[TextFieldViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];

//you will need to create a button on this new ViewController and use this code to dismiss it when done.

[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I guess I didnt frame my question correctly. I actually want something like on Yelp which has "Write a review" button. On click that button it shows an editable draft a review page which you can save it.

Comment: And inside the textviewcontroller I need to develop UITextView with editable text field rite ?

Comment: Yes, along with a button so you can dismiss the view when done. A "Save" button will work just fine. Dismiss it after saving.

Comment: Why are you using TRUE and FALSE in your code? Objective C uses YES and NO for BOOL type