# How to display the textfield when click on the button

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add UITextfield on click of UIButton and make it editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066875/how-to-add-uitextfield-on-click-of-uibutton-and-make-it-editable)

I want to display the UITextField which becomes editable when click on a button.
if any one knows please give me the answer.

Comment: you want to display it on the same uiview?

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBAction for the UIButton like this:

```
-(IBAction)showTextFied:(id)sender{
    yourTextField.editable=YES;//turn to editable mode if it's not
   [yourTextField becomeFirstReponder];//show the keyboard
}
```

Comment: You're welcome..remember to accept the answer if it's useful. And remember that you should use google (or SO search) to find the solution to this type of question...and read the documentation..cheers